# Changing alpha of a line in seaborn factorplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
```

In the code above, how can I change the `rest` line to an alpha of 0.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find proper objects of `FacetGrid` axes with `get_children()` method and set alpha for lines and markers. To change marker property in legend (`g._legend` object) find suitable  element of `legendHandles` and apply `set_alpha()` method:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)

# set alpha for marker (index 0) and for the rest line (indeces 3-6) 
plt.setp([g.ax.get_children()[0],g.ax.get_children()[3:7]],alpha=.5)

# modify marker in legend box
g._legend.legendHandles[0].set_alpha(.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]