# Seaborn Lineplot displays Index error, pandas plot fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I am having an interesting issue with displaying data with Seaborn lineplot.

I have item sales for 5 items over a period of time. I would like to see the sales after each product's introduction.

Here is my code:

```
items  = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(squeeze=False)
ax[0] = sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 1', data=item_sales, alpha=0.2) 
ax[1] = sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 2', data=item_sales, alpha=0.2) 
ax[2] = sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 3', data=item_sales, alpha=0.2) 
ax[3] = sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 4', data=item_sales, alpha=0.4)
ax[4] = sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 5', data=item_sales, alpha=0.2)
ax.set_ylabel('')  
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.title('Timeline of item sales')
plt.show()
```

This code errors out with the following line but draws 2 lines:

```
ax[1] = sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 2', data=item_sales, alpha=0.2) 

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

[image: Seaborn lineplot]

However, following line displays the plot perfectly without any errors:

```
item_sales.plot()
```

[image]

What could be the reason for the above error - the data is pretty clean and there are no missing values:

```
item_sales.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 36 entries, 0 to 35
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   Date Created  36 non-null     object
 1   Item 1        36 non-null     int64 
 2   Item 2        36 non-null     int64 
 3   Item 3        36 non-null     int64 
 4   Item 4        36 non-null     int64 
 5   Item 5        36 non-null     int64 
dtypes: int64(5), object(1)
memory usage: 1.8+ KB
```

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have multiple axes, try using just sns.lineplot(data=item_sales)

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work `ValueError: A wide-form input must have only numeric values.` Plus, this is not what I need, as I will highlight an Item by changing its alpha value, therefore I have to be able to manipulate the lines individually.

Comment: Your column zero is object type, so you have to choose just columns 1-5 to plot them as they are numeric. Take a look from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556499/changing-alpha-of-a-line-in-seaborn-factorplot , maybe it's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the `IndexError` is because your `ax` object is a 2-dimensional array and you're indexing on the first (length=1) dimension:

> squeeze bool, default: True 
> If False, no squeezing at all is done: the returned Axes object is always a 2D array containing Axes instances, even if it ends up being 1x1.

If you want to plot multiple lines on the same plot, you can just have them share the same `ax` by passing it to `seaborn` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# prepare sample data
items  = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5']
sales_data = dict(zip(items, np.random.randint(0, 25, (5, 30))))
item_sales = pd.DataFrame(sales_data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

sns.set_palette("tab10", n_colors=5)
sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 1', data=item_sales, alpha=0.3, ax=ax) 
sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 2', data=item_sales, alpha=0.3, ax=ax) 
sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 3', data=item_sales, alpha=0.3, ax=ax) 
sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 4', data=item_sales, alpha=1, ax=ax)
sns.lineplot(x=item_sales.index, y='Item 5', data=item_sales, alpha=0.3, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('')  
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.title('Timeline of item sales')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much @gherka, your reply was exactly where things were failing.
I made the changes you mentioned and now everything is in place.